# grails resource not loaded via https

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using grails with the resources plugin and bootstrap! When loading a page I get an ssl error because some of my resources are not loaded via https:

```
The page at 'https://localhost/blogpost/10' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed
insecure content from 'resource:/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff': this
content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

This file (glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) is defined in the bootstrap resources so I don't want to hardcode the https url in the file.

How can I tell my system (either grails or the resource plugin) to load the file via https?

Thanks for your help.

Thomas

Comment: Have you tried using `grails.resources.adhoc.includes = ['/fonts/**']` in `Config.groovy`?

Comment: Thanks for your proposition. I've tried It the result was still the same. In another test I tried to add it in 

`grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*','/fonts/*']` but it didn't work neither. I am still getting the above error in my browser. Are there any other suggestions? Thanks Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it. Don't know what the problem in my files is ...

```
    //resource url:'js/bootstrap.min.js'
    //resource url:'css/bootstrap.min.css'
    resource url:'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    resource url:'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using grails with the resources plugin and bootstrap too and was faced to the same "insecure content" problem.
To solve it i've just done this in config.groovy :

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 80
grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 443
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [ '/**': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL']
```